# How to disable fast charging on 2021 Macbook Pros?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power-management, apple-silicon

**Is there a way to disable fast charging on 2021 Macbook Pros?**

---

These are my reasons for doing so:

- lower speed charging produces less heat and is therefore less stressful for batteries
- I would always prefer to charge with a MagSafe cable as it reduces risk of the Macbook accidentally falling to the floor--therefore using USB-C to USB-C cable is not the best way to avoid fast charging
- when I'm going out to use Macbook away from my desk, the fewer items I need to carry the better--therefore carrying two chargers (140W for fast charging, 30W for lower voltage) is not optimal. In cases when wall outlets are not abundant enough where I spend my day, I would rather have an option for fast charging.

Comment: Apple has a huge team of people working on preserving battery life and performance. And you really don't know whether the impact of fast-charging is meaningful. There's really no need to second-guess them.

Comment: @benwiggy I don't agree with your statement. "There's really no need to second-guess them." If users never second guess products/features, you'd never see improvements and bug fixes.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to disable fast charging in software.

There's no need for it either. Apple's hardware automatically manages charging speeds to ensure that for example the temperature is kept within acceptable range.

That being said, [Fast Charging is only supported currently with higher wattage Apple Chargers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212755). If you really wish to avoid fast charging, you could simply use a charger that does not support fast charging. Your overall charge times might be slower however.

Currently, the 2021 16" MacBook Pro requires the 140W charger for fast charging, and the 2021 14" MacBook Pro requires the 96W or higher charger.

Comment: _"There's no need for it either."_: Apple [suggests avoiding temperatures higher than 35ºC](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/) when using MacBooks. However fast charging pushes the battery to 37ºC for most of the time, according to my tests with iStat Menus for 16" M1 Pro under minimal workload in a typical room temperature. While it's true that Apple does its best to balance between performance and longevity, it doesn't mean that using fast charging is _optimal_ for longevity-conscious users.

Comment: @yurkennis I suspect that advice is meant to avoid having the laptop in temps higher than 35C, likely because it provides little headroom to safely charge the battery. The laptop has temp sensors which is monitors and changes the charge rate accordingly.

Comment: @yurkennis You’re overlooking the fact that those 35 degrees is “ambient temperature” - the temperature of the battery is NOT “ambient temperature”. There’s simply nothing to worry about here - even if you’re “longevity-conscious”.

Comment: @yurkennis Yes: Apple's 35˚C guideline refer to the temperature in the room, not the temperature of components.

Comment: 96W is not required for the 14 inch. This laptop can charge within an hour or so on 67W, and 30W is the most practical for overnight if you are not doing heavy tasks. This is from experience.

Comment: Noone said it was required for the 14 inch. The answer talks specifically about the feature named “Fast Charge”, not about “charging fast”, which is very subjective.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in software. However, using 30W usb-c MacBook charger, you will be able to accomplish this (MAGSAFE WILL WORK).

Unplug your included USB-C to MagSafe cable from the end of the 96W/67W included power brick and plug the usb-c end of the cable into an [apple slow charger (30W, $50)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MY1W2AM/A/30w-usb-c-power-adapter). Now you should be able to slow charge using MagSafe.

If you don't want to spend your wallet on a charger, check out Anker's lineup instead. You can get a 33W nano for $33 & a 45W nano (somewhat faster) for $40. [Anker nano site](https://us.anker.com/collections/for-tablets/products/a2665)

For the convenience factor, you can just bring the fast charger with you and keep your slow charger at your desk.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official way of doing this, but there's a third party app, called [AlDente](https://apphousekitchen.com) that allows you to control much about the way your macbook charges.

It allows you to set a maximum battery temperature, so that when that threshold is reached, the charging process slows down or stops altogether, plus other useful features.

Please notice that, being a third-party, low-level app, it might have some issues. Although I have personally encountered only minor bugs, some  rare users might have had more serious problems.

Comment: Al Dente only allows to stop charging when temperature threshold is reached, not to slow down charging process in any way: ["When Heat Protection is enabled, AlDente will automatically stop charging when the battery temperature exceeds a set value to avoid a continuous increase of the temperature."](https://apphousekitchen.com/feature-explanation-heat-protection/) Not sure someone has done research on whether splitting fast-charging cycle into smaller chunks is healthier for battery than a single-chunk charging.

Comment: Oh right, the charge overall is slower, but instead on being uniformly slow it proceeds in a more stop and go fashion. Definitely not what you asked. However, AFIK heat is one of the major factors in reducing battery life, so keeping the battery at a lower temperature should help.  But, splitting the charging cycles could be a problem, I agree. Sadly I'm not aware of any studies about it either.